# PHPWORD reader - как получить доступ к свойству "Scale" у шрифта

Tags: phpword

Проблема:

Читаю файл `.docx` библиотекой `PHPWORD`. При переборе массива "`sections`" получаю доступ к элементу "`TextRun`", в котором перебираю элементы (объекты) "`Text`". У объекта "`Text`" есть свойства, которые получаются c помощью метода `$font = $text->getFontStyle()`. Читаю свойства методом `$fontFamily = $font->getName()`. Свойства размер (`size`), цвет(`color`) и т.д. читаются нормально, однако свойство "`scale`" (масштаб текста) и некоторые другие свойства всегда пустые.

Как вытащить свойства из текста?

Что испробовано:

разные версии библиотеки `PHPWord`, просмотр всего объекта после чтения `$phpWord = $objReader->load($filename); debug($phpWord);` не дает положительного результата (объект больше, но нигде свойств также нет).

Еще замечена особенность - если стиль текста стоит по умолчанию - то и свойство размера шрифта остается пустым, если шрифт изменить - значение появляется. Масштаб конечно менялся в разных значенияx в документе, но значение в свойстве не появлялось.

Может некорректно работает ридер? Как это поправить.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решено самостоятельно. Проблема в том, что в классе vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Reader\2007\AbstractPart есть метод readFontStyle(), который формирует в переменной $styleDefs (массиве) дефолтные поля для чтения. В данных полях необходимо добавить 'spacing'=> array(self::READ_VALUE,  'w:spacing'), 'scale' => array(self::READ_VALUE,  'w:w'). Не совсем понятно, почему именно этих полей не было изначально. На скорость никак не влияет.

Вопрос закрыт.